# React Native: How to handle the deprecation of the lifecycle methods with ListView?

Tags: reactjs, listview, react-native, redux, react-lifecycle

I'm currently learning React Native. I want to write a ListView. The tutorial I'm following uses the deprecated method `componentWillMount`, which is now called `UNSAFE_componentWillMount`. I googled an people said one should replace that method with `componentDidMount`. My problem is when I add this method to my code, the app breaks.

Here is the code:

```
/* @flow */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ListView } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ListItem from "./ListItem";

class LibraryList extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.libraries);
  };

  renderRow = library => <ListItem library={library} />;

  render() {
    return <ListView dataSource={this.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderRow} />;
  }
}

LibraryList.propTypes = {
  libraries: PropTypes.array
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { libraries: state.libraries };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

And here is the error message that I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'rowIdentities' of undefined`. Which method am I supposed to use here, or how can I fix this?

Comment: This is because componentDidMount runs after first render. So, in the first render if there is no data that holds rowIdentites you get this error. You need to render your component conditionally. Where does rowIdentites come from? dataSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a `FlatList` instead. I found out that `ListView` is deprecated :) Here is the code I ended up using:

```
/* @flow */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FlatList } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ListItem from "./ListItem";

class LibraryList extends Component {
  state = {
    dataSource: []
  };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({ dataSource: this.props.libraries });
  };

  renderRow = ({ item: library }) => <ListItem library={library} />;

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.dataSource}
        renderItem={this.renderRow}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
      />
    );
  }
}

LibraryList.propTypes = {
  libraries: PropTypes.array
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { libraries: state.libraries };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```